# UISlider - select when touch down off of thumb

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, uikit

In order to "grab" the handle of a ui slider, one must touch down on top of it. I'm interested in modifying the behavior so that users merely need to touch down anywhere in the uislider. On touch down, the handle would jump to whichever position the user is touching. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did it by overriding touchesBegan:withEvent: in a subclass of UISlider. You don't have to check for how close the touch is to the slider, since you'll only get a touch event if you're over the slider.  This code works for a slider set up with the default 0 to 1 scale.

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    float xPoint = [[[event allTouches]anyObject]locationInView:self].x;
    [self setValue:xPoint/self.frame.size.width];
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but I just wanted to mention that I came up with a different way to do this recently. In a nutshell:

```
- (BOOL)beginTrackingWithTouch:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    BOOL ignored = [super beginTrackingWithTouch:touch withEvent:event];
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)continueTrackingWithTouch:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    BOOL ignored = [super continueTrackingWithTouch:touch withEvent:event];
    return YES;
}
```

I think this is a safer way of addressing the problem, because you're not having to generate the slider's value manually. You never know when Apple might introduce integer/detent sliders, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head I'd say you should watch for touches on the view. When a touch is detected, check to see how close it is to the body of the `UISlider`. If it's within a certain range, do (pseudo)

```
sliderValue = sliderMinValue + (sliderMaxValue-sliderMinValue)/(xCoordOfTouch - sliderLeftSideXCoord)/sliderLength
```

So basically you're calculating the value that the slider should have based on where the user touched in relation to the frame of the slider.

It's funny you mention this, because I was thinking about doing the same thing today. If I get something up and running I'll post it (but don't hold your breath).

Answer (score 0):

rdelmar's answer doesn't work if you have minimum or maximum value images. I modified rdelmar's touchesBegan:withEvent: method to see only touches on the track and not in the margins.

Hope this helps

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    float xPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self].x;
    float trackWidth = [self trackRectForBounds:self.bounds].size.width;
    float margin = (self.bounds.size.width - trackWidth) / 2;
    float xOffset = xPoint - margin;

    if (xOffset >= 0.0 && xOffset <= trackWidth) {
        float newValue = xOffset / trackWidth;
        [self setValue:newValue animated:YES];
        [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    }
}
```